# Direct product of modules and the axiom of choice

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, axiom-of-choice, direct-product

Studying the differences between the direct product and the direct sum of modules, my book candidly says that we don't need the axiom of choice to know that the direct product of modules is a non-empty set.

I have thought about it for a while, but it seems to be much more subtle than I have conceived. How to see this fact?

Comment: I think it's because you know each module contains zero, and so you can construct the zero element of the direct product using this. You don't have to *choose* arbitrarily many elements.

Comment: This is what I came up with, but I wasn't sure and I went to the trouble to use the result that any module is homomorphic to a free module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modules have a 0 element. It is a distinct element that is uniformly definable, so that means that you can always choose that one.